# Cancel button on browser of WebAuthenticator cause Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.WebAuthenticationSession Code=1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

Im using xamarin essentials WebAuthenticator for social media login. After the browser open with login form is user press the cancel button on browser it gives me "Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.WebAuthenticationSession Code=1" error. How can i choose cancel without any error?

```
 try
        {
            var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                             new Uri(App.AuthServer + "/mobileauth/Facebook"),
                             new Uri("MyApp://"));

            var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is that error means your login has been cancelled? See document [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsessionerrorcode?language=objc)

Comment: Is there a way use cancel button without error? @JackHua-MSFT Do you know how do i clean session for safari for logout? I need connect with new user but browser always remember active user.

Comment: It seems you can't clean session of safari browser.

Comment: Yes, can you help me for it. I dont know how can i do it. I tried to write a dependency service but there is no example of it.

Comment: I mean you can't do that.

Comment: Okay but then how can i sign up with different users when using web auth? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use the WebAuthenticator to open the logout page, that will clear the session & cookies.